# What is the best possible way to avoid the sql injection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-injection, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.2

The following code is prone to sql injection

```
params[:id] = "1) OR 1=1--"
User.delete_all("id = #{params[:id]}")
```

My question is by doing the following will be the best solution to avoid sql injection or not. If not then what is the best way to do so?

```
User.delete_all("id = #{params[:id].to_i}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
User.where(id: params[:id]).delete_all
```

---

Ok sorry for Rails 2.x its:

```
User.delete_all(["id = ?", params[:id]])
```

[Check doc](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.2/ActiveRecord/Base/delete_all/class)

Btw, be sure you want to use `delete_all` instead of `destroy_all`, the former doesn't trigger callbacks.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose this is the best possible way to avoid sql injection. Is there any drawback of using to_i?

Comment: Not particularly, but I dont see the point of this paeudo validation either

Comment: I mean, Rails handles this for you, so dont pollute your code

Answer (score 1):

You can use this also

```
User.delete(params[:id])
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers answer this well for Rails and it'll work fine if you follow their suggestions.  In a more generic setting when you have to handle this yourself you can typically use a regular expression to extract a value that's in an expected format.  This is really simple with an integer id.  Think of it like this:

```
if params[:id] =~ /(\d+)/
  safe_id = $1.to_i
  # do something with safe_id now
end
```

That gets a little more complicated when you're handling strings and arbitrary data.  If you have to handle such data then you can use the quoting methods available for the database adapters.  In Rails this is ultimately rolled into a consistent interface:

```
safe_string = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(unsafe_string)
```

For most database systems this will handle single quotes and backslashes in a special manner.

If you're outside of Rails you will have to use the quoting methods specific to your database adapter, but usage is quite similar.

The takeaway:

1. If your data has a particular format, enforce the format with a regular expression
2. Otherwise, use your database adapter's quoting function to make the data "safe" for use in a query
3. Rails will handle most of this for you if you properly use the various methods and "conditions"

Answer (score 0):

Use the rails methods to pass your `where` options. You can always hardcode them, as in the example that you give, but the usual way would be something like:

```
User.where(:id => params[:id]).delete_all
User.where("id = ?", params[:id]).delete_all
User.where("id = :id", :id => params[:id]).delete_all
```

They are well tested and in case a new vulnerability is detected, an update will fix the problem and your code will not need to be changed.

By the way, if you just want to delete 1 record based on its id, what I would do is:

User.find(params[:id]).destroy